# Properties File multi-line values using PropertiesConfiguration

Tags: java, apache, properties-file, apache-commons-config

So far, I have this project where I read in a properties file using PropertiesConfiguration (from Apache), edit the values I would like to edit, and then save change to the file. It keeps the comments and formatting and such, but one thing it does change is taking the multi-line values formatted like this:

```
key=value1,\
    value2,\
    value3
```

and turns it into the array style:

```
key=value1,value2,value3
```

I would like to be able to print those lines formatted as the were before. 
I did this via this method:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(configFile);
config.setProperty(key,value);
config.save();
```

Comment: This is not possible with current apache-commons-config implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a work around in case anyone else needs this functionality. Also, there is probably a better way to do this, but this solution currently works for me.

First, set your PropertiesConfiguration delimiter to the new line character like so:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(configFile);
config.setListDelimiter('\n');
```

Then you will need to iterate through and update all properties (to set the format):

```
Iterator<String> keys = config.getKeys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();

        config.setProperty(key,setPropertyFormatter(key, config.getProperty(key))) ;

    }
```

use this method to format your value list data (as shown above):

```
private List<String> setPropertyFormatter(String key, Object list) {
    List<String> tempProperties = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<?> propertyIterator = PropertyConverter.toIterator(list, '\n');;
    String indent = new String(new char[key.length() + 1]).replace('\0', ' ');

    Boolean firstIteration = true;
    while (propertyIterator.hasNext()) {
        String value = propertyIterator.next().toString();

        Boolean lastIteration = !propertyIterator.hasNext();

        if(firstIteration && lastIteration) {
            tempProperties.add(value);
            continue;
        }

        if(firstIteration) {
            tempProperties.add(value + ",\\");
            firstIteration = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (lastIteration) { 
            tempProperties.add(indent + value);
            continue;
        } 

        tempProperties.add(indent + value + ",\\");
    }



    return tempProperties;
}
```

Then it is going to be almost correct, except the save function takes the double backslash that is stored in the List, and turns it into 4 back slashes in the file! So you need to replace those with a single backslash. I did this like so:

```
try {
        config.save(new File(filePath));


        byte[] readIn = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
        String replacer = new String(readIn, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replace("\\\\\\\\", "\\");

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath, false), "UTF-8"));
        bw.write(replacer);
        bw.close();

} catch (ConfigurationException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With commons-configuration2, you would handle such cases with a custom PropertiesWriter implementation, as described in its [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html) under "Custom properties readers and writers" (Reader biased though).

A writer provides a way to govern writing of each character that is to be written to the properties file, so you can achieve pretty much anything you desire with it (via `PropertiesWriter.write(String)`). There is also a convenient method that writes proper newlines (`PropertiesWriter.writeln(String)`).

For example, I had to handle classpath entries in a Netbeans Ant project project.properties file:

```java
public class ClasspathPropertiesWriter extends PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesWriter {
    
    public ClasspathPropertiesWriter(Writer writer, ListDelimiterHandler delimiter) {
        super(writer, delimiter);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeProperty(String key, Object value, boolean forceSingleLine) throws IOException {
        switch (key) {
            case "javac.classpath":
            case "run.classpath":
            case "javac.test.classpath":
            case "run.test.classpath":
                String str = (String) value;
                String[] split = str.split(":");
                if (split.length > 1) {
                    write(key);
                    write("=\\");
                    writeln(null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                        write("    ");
                        write(split[i]);
                        if (i != split.length - 1) {
                            write(":\\");
                        }
                        writeln(null);
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    super.writeProperty(key, value, forceSingleLine);
                }                
                break;

            default:
                super.writeProperty(key, value, forceSingleLine);
                break;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```java
public class CustomIOFactory extends PropertiesConfiguration.DefaultIOFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesWriter createPropertiesWriter(
            Writer out, ListDelimiterHandler handler) {
        return new ClasspathPropertiesWriter(out, handler);
    }
    
}
```

```java
Parameters params = new Parameters();
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<Configuration> builder =
    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<Configuration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
    .configure(params.properties()
        .setFileName("project.properties")
        .setIOFactory(new CustomIOFactory());
Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();
builder.save();
```

Comment: Note that the code above is just a quick example. Production code should handle this in a more robust way.